# How to sort in python with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list with sublists as follows:

```
result = [ ['helo', 10], ['bye', 50], ['yeah', 5], ['candy',30] ]
```

I want to sort this with three conditions:
first, by highrest integer in index 2 of sublist, then by length of word in index 1 of sublist, and finally by alphabetical order in the 1st index of sublist.

I tried to do the following but it does not work:

```
finalresult = sorted(result, key=lambda word: (-word[1], len(word), word[0]))
```

This sorts it by the highest integer and alphabet order but not by length of word.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: When trying to debug bits like this promoting the lambda to a named function can make it much easier to see the issue. Lambdas are concise but they are not the most readable construct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

every element is a list of 2 elements, sorting by the length of the list is useless because all of them has the same length, maybe you want to sort by the length of the first element so

```
finalresult = sorted(result, key=lambda word: (-word[1], len(word[0]), word[0]))
```

Comment: @HellMan you're welcome, if it solved the problem please consider to accept the answer ^^