# Python sort array of arrays by multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array by a given set of indexes and prioritize the value being in that index.  As of now, I can not get the sort methods to sort by a specific index throughout the entire array because 0 value causes issues.

For example, first sort by index 1, then by index 0, then 2

```
tmpList = [[0,-10,0],[0,10,0],[0,5,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,-1],[0,0,0],[0,0,5]]
Res = sorted(tmpList, key=lambda x: x[1] )
>>[[0, -10, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5], [0, 5, 0], [0, 10, 0]]
```

I need more flexibility in this sorting, so that I can prioritize a value other than zero being in the index as priority, so it would sort as:

`[[0,-10,0],[0,5,0],[0,10,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,-1],[0,0,5],[0,0,0]]`

[How to sort in python with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182895/how-to-sort-in-python-with-multiple-conditions) has a similar task, but the zero problem remains

Comment: "first sort by index 1, then by index 0, then 2" does not produce your desired output.

Comment: to me it does, if the condition is non-zero

Comment: So you want `0` to sort to the end? E.g. `yoursort([1,8,3,0,4,9,0]) == [1,3,4,8,9,0,0]`?

Comment: I want to sort based on the index priority on condition it is nonzero, so -10, then 5, then 10 as the index 1.  The sorted function is considering 0 to mean remove the priority

Comment: So what should be done with the `0`'s?

Comment: @user1938107 Why is `[0, 0, 0]` before `[0, 0, -1]`?

Comment: Why is `[0,0,0]` before anything?

Comment: Be given priority last.  0,0,0 is sorted after priority of index 1, It sorts because it is the first item that has past the first condition of index 0.  1,0,0 is before 0,0,-1 because index 0 is priority over index 2.

Comment: @user1938107 "first sort by index 1, then by index 0, then 2" Both `[0, 0, 0]` and `[0, 0, -1]` have the same index 1 and index 0, so they should be sorted by the index 2. `-1` is smaller than `0`, so `[0, 0, -1]` should be first.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen yes that logic can work as well, I was thinking a different method of priority in the list for the first index.

Comment: @user1938107 That's the only logic you told us; fix your question with proper examples and explanations, and we shall then answer your question properly.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen sorry I edit to clarify the logic i was using

Comment: @user1938107 There are two desired outputs now, one with `[0, 0, 0]` at the end (that's what my answer provides), and the other one with `[0, 0, 0]` floatng in the middle. Which one do you want?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen your answer is correct, edited question to remove two possibilities

Comment: @Cyphase I gave an explanation in the question which is now edited out for clarity) in case you were still curious what I was talking about.

Comment: @user Much better now. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When sorting by multiple conditions, you should always use `tuple`s.
The Python's built-in `sorted()` will sort the list by comparing the first values in the tuples, if they're equal then the second values, if they're also equal then the third ones, etc.

Example: `sorted([(0, 5, 1), (1, 3, 4), (0, -3, 1), (1, 3, 5)])` will output

```
(0, -3, 1),
(0, 5, 1),
(1, 3, 4),
(1, 3, 5)
```

If you wish for the sort to happen in a custom order, in your case index `1` having priority over index `0`, you can do that by providing a lambda function that simply re-arranges these tuples:

```
>>> l = [(0, 5, 1), (1, 3, 4), (0, -3, 1), (1, 3, 5)]
>>> sorter = lambda x: (x[1], x[0], x[2])
>>> sorted_l = sorted(l, key=sorter)
```

This will output:

```
(0, -3, 1),
(1, 3, 4),
(1, 3, 5),
(0, 5, 1)
```

Now if you want the elements with `0` at index 1 (`x[1] == 0`) to be the last, you must add this condition to the beginning of the tuple returned by the `sorter` function:

```
sorter = lambda x: (x[1] == 0, x[1], x[0], x[2])
```

That's the exact same as before, but with `x[1] == 0` added to the beginning. This comparison will yield either `True` or `False`, and since `False` is represented as `0` and `True` is represented as `1`, we can deduce that `False < True` when sorting, thus those elements where `x[1] != 0` will be first. Essentially this sorts those elements with a beginning `0` to the very end. You can repeat this for `x[0] == 0` and `x[2] == 0` too, so your final version would then be: `sorted(tmpList, key=lambda x: (x[1] == 0, x[1], x[0] == 0, x[0], x[2] == 0, x[2]))`

Comment: I don't think this is doing what I am describing, I get [0, -10, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0] as the first 3

Comment: @user1938107 Your "desired output" doesn't match with what you told us. My solution works for the "first sort by index 1, then by index 0, then 2".

Comment: Your solution does not prioritize non-zero elements.

Comment: "so that I can prioritize a value other than zero", also, your solution is what I link to in the question

Comment: @user1938107 Fixed, try now. Sorry, I misunderstood the zero part.

Comment: Yes thank you, sorry for the confusion.  The comparison on the index, is this the cmp argument referred to in the python docs for sorted?

Comment: @user no, we're using the `key` argument. That's just how tuples work: `(1, 0, 3) > (1, 6, 8) > (2, 1, 8)`

Comment: I was referring to x[1]==0

Comment: @user `x[1] == 0` is just a comparison which returns `True` or `False`. When sorting, `False < True`. Thus `(False, 1)` gets sorted before `(True, 1)`